# Bubble sort the total number of comparisons and swaps

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

I have this code for bubble sort in c++. At first it generates random numbers and puts them inside an array. After that I call my bubbleSort function, which does the sorting. Everything works fine. However I was curious how can I find a number of total comparisons and number swapping that bubble sort makes?
I created a CountBubbleSort integer for comparisons. However I'm not sure in which part of my code should I increment it. I was thinking to add it after second for loop, inside first one. Hope you understand what I mean. Is it right or not? Number of comparisons defines this formula n*(n-1))/2. And with swaps it is  3*(n-1). But how can I implement it to my code? Thanks for the help guys.

```
void swap(double *xp, double *yp)
{
    double temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

double *Data;
double* A;
double n, temp;

void generate(int _n, const char *_file);
void read(const char *_file);   
void printArray(double arr[], int n); 
void bubbleSort(double arr[], int n);

int main()
{
    int m;
    int CountBubbleSort = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Amount of random numbers you want: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Generating random data ..." << endl;
    generate(m, "duom.txt");
    cout << "Reading data" << endl;
    read("duom.txt");
    A = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = Data[i];
    }

    cout << "Randomly generated array" << endl;
    printArray(A, n);

    // Bubble Sort
    bubbleSort(A, n);

    cout << "Array after bubble sort" << endl;
    printArray(A, n);

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(double arr[], int n)
{
    bool swapped;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        // Should I add CountBubbleSort += i here or not?
        if (swapped == false)
            break;
    }
}

void printArray(double arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relatively straightforward change:

- Increment comparison count before the `if` statement
- Increment the swap counter inside the `if` statement

Take two `int&` parameters for the count, like this:

```
void bubbleSortCounted(double arr[], int n, int& countComparisons, int& countSwaps);
```

The code incrementing the counters would look like this:

```
countComparisons++;
if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
{
    countSwaps++;
    swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
    swapped = true;
}
```

The call from the `main()` would look like this:

```
int cmp = 0, swp = 0;
bubbleSort(A, n, cmp, swp);
std::cout << cmp << " comparisons, " << swp << " swaps" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

> However I was curious how can I find a number of total comparisons and number swapping that bubble sort makes? I created a CountBubbleSort integer for comparisons. However I'm not sure in which part of my code should I increment it.

There's exactly one line in your `bubbleSort()` function where you actually compare two elements in the array, so it stands to reason that if you want to count the number of times you compare elements, you should increment the counter either immediately before or immediately after the comparison happens.

Comment: Yes, but don't take my word for it: try it on a small list and make sure that you get the number of comparisons that you expect, or step through the code in a debugger and confirm that the counter is incremented every time two elements are compared.

Comment: Thanks for the help:)